# How to remove "amp;" from getting sent in XML?

Tags: ruby, xml, ampersand

i have a string "Travel & Hospitality". like this.

When i sent it through XML API the output is like below.

```
        "Travel &amp; Hospitality"
```

i tried removing it with ruby code like below and sent it through XML.

```
       "Travel &amp; Hospitality".gsub("&amp;","&").

       <Specialization__c>Travel &amp; Hospitality</Specialization__c>
```

even though gsub is removing "amp;" again while sending it through XML tags again the amp; word is coming.

How can i remove it.my desired output is

```
     "Travel & Hospitality"
```

Comment: Note that `&amp;` in XML means `&`. Whoever is receiving your XML will get the string as `Travel & Hospitality` and not `Travel &amp; Hospitality` unless they are clueless about XML.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are doing and where it is going wrong. An `&` should always be turned into `&amp;` when putting data into XML form, and should be turned back into `&` when extracting it from XML form into plain text.

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn't allow such a thing. & is not allowed to appear unescaped.

You could have an XML file like this instead:

```
<Specialization__c><![CDATA[Travel & Hospitality]]></Specialization__c>
```

That would work, but the problem is how to convince your XML output library to do something like that. It might not even be possible at all. (I might be wrong about that last part. I know nothing about ruby)

Comment: Very easily, `Nokogiri::XML::Builder#cdata`, `REXML::CData` are the relevant bits for the two most common XML libraries (though OP doesn't say how they construct their XML).

Comment: its not working the output is, <Stream__c>&lt;![CDATA[Non - STEM: Humanities, Commerce, Law, Arts, Language, travel &amp; hospitality]]&gt;</Stream__c>

Comment: @John yes. Like I said it's not possible to make an XML file that contains an unescaped &. However it's possible to make XML files that use CDATA sections such as the ones I showed, to escape special characters like &. It's possible to make XML files such as these. However, I have no idea how to convince Ruby to do that, nor if there is even a way to. You're better off just accepting that your XML contains an escaped &amp; as there is no problem with that and it's the way it's meant to be.

Comment: You just wrapped your literal string into `<![CDATA[...]]>`, which obviously the XML engine has to escape (`&lt;...&gt;`). You would have to construct CDATA programmatically so that XML engine doesn't think it's a string. I showed before the way to do that for the two most common XML engines, but without more data about how you are actually constructing the XML (i.e. "show us the code!"), there is not much more I can say. Furthermore, as I stated on the question comment, the whole thing is misguided because XML is not meant to be read by humans, and the machine should know it's actually `&`.

Comment: This is... kind of an answer. But what would be the benefit of it? The personal satisfaction of seeing the desired string in the XML? There's no way that this is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Max There is really no benefit, but I thought it was best to be factual and let it sink in the OP the absurdity of wanting & to appear as-in in a format that doesn't allow it.